# Python3 How to call to method from one class in other class

Tags: python

I have two classes A and B, I want to run a method from class A in class B. I wrote the code but it's not working, I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'testPrint'

My classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 'A'

    def test_1(self):
        i = 1
        print('Function test_1 in class A: ')
        x = self.testPrint(i) # i think error is here
        return x

    def testPrint(self, i):
        return 'testPrint: '+i

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 'B'

    def b1(self):
        print('wywolanie funkcji z klasy b')
        f = A.test_1(self)
        return f
```

Run the program

```
b = B()
b.b1()
```

Comment: Try: `f = A().test_1()`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer then there is the error: TypeError: test_1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you understand why you are getting `AttributeError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instanciate class A:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 'A'

    def test_1(self):
        i = 1
        print('Function test_1 in class A: ')
        x = self.testPrint(i) # i think error is here
        return x

    def testPrint(self, i):
        return 'testPrint: %s' % i

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 'B'

    def b1(self):
        print('wywolanie funkcji z klasy b')
        f = A().test_1()
        return f


b = B()
res = b.b1()
print (res)
```

Returns (Python3):

```
wywolanie funkcji z klasy b
Function test_1 in class A: 
testPrint:1
```